# Anime where MC learns the abilities of his foes, in destroyed or war-torn city

Tags: needless

I'm looking for an anime I would love to draw or watch again and here are the details

- Good graphics all around
- Very, VERY few episodes, about 20-40
- Includes superpowers (a girl shapeshifting , a guy learning everybody else's abilities , etc).
- Protagonist is a guy that learns the abilities of his foes, there is one more guy with this power who is supposedly stronger but I think he loses in the end.
- It's about a destroyed city or a war is going on and they are living in some kind of church.
- The girl comes with the Protagonist in the start, she wears purple, very short top and skirt, it reveals her belly and she has big breasts, blue hair
- A woman that doesn't talk is an enemy, and she uses aromas as a special ability, and also uses a board to write (so to speak she is talking like that).

I think that's it.

Comment: It would be nice to have more anime that are short enough that 20-40 episodes wouldn't be considered "Very, VERY few". I don't have that much time in my life. :P

Comment: 24 episodes isn't "Very, VERY few". A lot of anime have only 12-24 épisodes.

Comment: I'd say the majority only have 12 episodes, or one season's worth. A select few make it to 24. Very, VERY few anime get to boast 40+ and those are typically the "AAA" titles such as One Piece or Bleach or Naruto

Answer (score 6):

I guarantee you, you're thinking of "[Needless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needless)".

Some details:

> Very, VERY few episodes , about 20-40 episodes

Needless has 24 episodes.

> Includes superpowers (a girl shapeshifting , a guy learning everybody else's abilities , etc).

From Wikipedia: "The Black Spot eventually becomes populated by outcasts, some of whom, as a result of the contamination, gain various powers called "fragments". Those in possession of such fragments come to be known as "Needless".

> Protagonist is a guy that learns the abilities of his foes, there is one more guy with this power who is supposedly stronger but I think he loses in the end.

From Wikipedia, the main character is "Adam Blade": "Adam Blade is a destroyer priest who lives in the church in Sector 533. He has a metal collar engraved with the characters '079.AB.' affixed to his neck. He has inhuman strength and endurance as well as accelerated healing, plus a skeletal structure attached with a special metal called Orichalcum. It was revealed that he is a clone of the strongest Needless, 'The Second Christ'. His only flaw is his attraction to cute, young girls. His fragment 'Zero' allows him to learn the attacks of his enemies, after being hit by it or seeing it, also being able to combine other abilities learned as well. His special move is 'Death Verdict', the final pronouncement when taking an enemy's life."

> Its about a destroyed city or a war is going on and they are living in some kind of church

From Wikipedia: "This anime is set in the year 2130 (the beginning date remains unclear), 50 years after World War III. The war has left a crater where Tokyo once stood, a place now filled with contaminated rubble."